# curvature node on eevee without AO

Tags: eevee-render-engine

is there a way to simulate a curvature node in eevee without using the AO node?

to create a real node that places textures made with procedural maps on the corners and folds of a model?

thanks

Comment: it doesn't seem possible to do it in Eevee   :((

Comment: what do you mean with curvature node? RGB curves?

Comment: cavity node
that positions the texture only in the model's recesses